# Internationalization inside html function of JQUERY

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm doing the internationalization of a PHP project.
in PHP I use the getttext() function and poedit program. 
example:

```
<?php 
  echo gettext("Hello world");
?>
```

Hello World will be the key with the associated translated words:
It all works.
I haven't any idea how  to translate the .js file with html function of JQUERY.

For example:
inside javascript file, I have

```
if(exchange=='mo'){
    $(#hopen.title).html("NEW WORD");
}
```

the question is: How can I call the gettext function to "NEW WORD" and then use it with poedit program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to call gettext / php from your javascript file every time you need a translation as that would mean you would have to make an ajax request to the server for each text.

Instead, you could generate an object in php with all the keys and translations that you need and send that to the browser and make it available as a global variable in javascript.

```
<?php
...
$needed_translations = array(
    'Hello world' => gettext("Hello world")
    ...
);
?>
<script>
var needed_translations = <?php echo json_encode($needed_translations); ?>;
// or
window.needed_translations = <?php echo json_encode($needed_translations); ?>;
</script>
```

If your javascript file is loaded after this or your code is located in a document ready block, you will have access to this global variable and can use it wherever you want:

```
if(exchange=='mo'){
    $(#hopen.title).html( needed_translations['Hello world'] );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, 
It's very useful that solution,
but there is one way to call the gettext directly on javascript?
for example:
    if(exchange=='mo'){
        $(#hopen.title).html(gettext("NEW WORD"));
    }

and after I can execute the xgettext in linux in order to generate the file mo?

Comment: @raoen The php has already finished processing by the time the javascript starts in the browser so the only way to do that, would be by making an ajax call and have a php script that returns the correct value. But that is lots of requests and extra work so I would not recommend that.